# How to do operations with decimals in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point

Well, I have here two variables with values such as 4.000,00 and 1.400,50.
The problem is that operations with these variables are not working. For example, if I try to do something like:

```
$num1 = 4.000.00;
$num2 = 1.400.50;
$result = $num1 - $num2;

echo "$result";
```

This not works. I have a syntax error.
I've tried using bc, but nothing works. Is there way to do this?

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, I will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [float numbers are invalid](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float). Only one decimal per float (and commas are not allowed):

```
$num1 = 4000.00;
$num2 = 1400.50;
$result = $num1 - $num2;

echo $result;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/308433)

FYI, the quotes around `$result` is unnecessary so I removed them.

Comment: Nice! But the value that I receive is 4.000,00. So, to operate with this, I need to remove the dot and replace the comma by one dot? Should I use str_replace or number_format?

Comment: If the values are in a format that causes this error you definitely need to transform them. number_format() should work for this.

Comment: @Dyan Use [`numfmt_parse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php) To convert your numbers back from a formatted number to a normal number